# How to safely toggle a primefaces panel using a poll within datagrid

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a problem toggling some panels within a datagrid:

```
                <h:form id="formxy">

                    <p:panel id="panelxy" header="xy">  
                        <p:focus />

                        <p:dataGrid var="page" value="#{xyViewBean.xyPages}" columns="1" id="grid" paginator="false">
                            <p:column>
                                <p:panel header="#{page.name}" style="text-align:left" toggleable="true" closable="false" toggleSpeed="500" collapsed="#{page.verifiedBy!=null}" >
                                    <h:panelGrid>
                                        <h:column>
                                            <p:inputText value="${page.url}" required="true" label="text" size="60" disabled="false" onclick="poll.stop()" onfocus="poll.stop()" onblur="poll.start()"/>
                                            <p:commandButton value="xy" update="grid" actionListener="#{xyViewBean.handleClose}">
                                                <f:attribute name="xyPage" value="${page}" />
                                            </p:commandButton>

                                        </h:column>
                                    </h:panelGrid>
                                </p:panel>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataGrid> 
                        <p:poll interval="3" widgetVar="poll" update="grid" actionListener="#{xyViewBean.finishedListener}"/>
```

As you can see the status of being collapsed or not is dynamic. Clicking the xy button executes the handleClose actionListener which sets the "verifiedBy" field. Therefore this panel should be collapsed. Also the comandbutton updates the complete datagrid nothing happens. Reloading the page shows the panel collapsed. So i thought it would work, but after three seconds the primefaces poll updates the datagrid again and the panel is not collapsed anymore. So panels being updated by the poll ignore the collapse attribute?! Any idea?

primefaces:2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

In case that did not work, you could try an extra : 
before the first id. That seemed to work.

```
<p:commandButton value="xy" update=":formxy:grid" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
<p:commandButton value="xy" update="formxy:grid" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but that changes nothing. I think that the update in both -the command button and the poll- are working fine but the "collapsed="#{page.verifiedBy!=null}"" is being ignored when the poll and the commandbutton update the grid

Comment: Ok, can you try updating the panel with update="formxy:panelxy"

Comment: unfortunately its still the same. only refreshing the browser collapses the panel and after the poll updates the panel as you suggested, the panel is not collapsed anymore

Comment: @cagatay-civici using "rendered" instead of "collapsed" works fine. the panels disappear. any idea?